# Multiple select of max values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
 ID  cbk           due_16_30        due_31_60 
  1  2018-06-19    5                200
  2  2018-06-19    100              -5
  1  2018-06-19    -2               2
  2  2018-06-18    20               Null
  2  2018-06-18    50               22
  1  2018-06-18    30               150
```

I want to select the max `due_16_30` and max `due_31_60` from the latest date, where date is between some `start date` and `end date`. How can I do that in `PostgreSQL`?
**UPDATE 1:**
Thank you for your answers! I have found one more complication - what if I need to do the same, but for different ID? Now what I see - it takes the latest date from between and if there is no row for the specific ID for that date - that ID is missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
select cbk, max(due_16_30), max(due_31_60)
from [table]
where cbk = (select max(cbk) 
            from [table] 
            where cbk >= start_date and 
                  cbk <= end_date
            ) 
group by cbk;
```

Comment: can you see please my update, there one more complication appeared :)

Answer (score 2):

First get the latest date in subquery, an then get the max due dates :

```
select max(due_16_30) as max_due_16_30, 
       max(due_31_60) as max_due_31_60
  from tab
 where cbk in 
(
  select max(cbk)
    from tab
   where cbk between date'2018-06-18' and date'2018-06-19'
);
```

[*DB-Fiddle Demo*](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ky2mm7zsVNavDJmDWKRZJG/3)

Comment: You need `=` rather than `IN` clause.

Comment: @YogeshSharma why..?

Comment: Because op wants latest date between `start_dt` & `end_dt`. If so,  then you don't need to use `IN` clause.

Comment: can you see please my update, there one more complication appeared :)

Answer (score 1):

An alter approach would be `LIMTIT` clause with `subquery` :

```
select t.cbk, max(t.due_16_30), max(t.due_31_60)
from table t
where cbk = (select t1.cbk
             from table t1
             where t1.cbk >= start_dt and t1.cbk <= end_dt
             order by t1.cbk desc
             limit 1
            )
group by t.cbk;
```

Comment: can you see please my update, there one more complication appeared :)

Comment: @Chiefir. . . You should ask another question as because this would be your other requirements with sample date & output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select due_16_30,due_31_60 
from
(
    SELECT * 
    from your_table 
    ORDER BY cbk DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) as T
```

Comment: but this does not select the latest date from that between?