# Multiple select of max values in PostgreSQL for specific ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
ID  cbk           due_16_30        due_31_60 
  1  2018-06-19    5                200
  2  2018-06-19    100              -5
  1  2018-06-19    -2               2
  2  2018-06-18    20               Null
  2  2018-06-18    50               22
  1  2018-06-18    30               150
  3  2018-06-18    20               70
```

I want to select for each specific `ID` a max `due_16_30` and a max `due_31_60` from the latest date, where date is between some `start date` and `end date`. How can I do that in PostgreSQL?
P.S. This is how the 2nd part is solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51493567/8495108

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (id) id, max(due_16_30), max(due_31_60) 
from t
where date >= ? and date < ?
group by id, date
order by id, date desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
select t.id, t.cbk, max(t.due_16_30), max(t.due_31_60)
from table t
where cbk = (select t1.cbk
             from table t1
             where t1.cbk >= start_dt and t1.cbk <= end_dt
             order by t1.cbk desc
             limit 1
            )
group by t.id, cbk
order by t.id desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: but it will take only last date? what if there is no row for one ID for that date?

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider *myID* parameter for both subquery and outer query as :

```
select ID,
       cbk,
       max(due_16_30) as max_due_16_30, 
       max(due_31_60) as max_due_31_60
  from tab
 where cbk in 
(
  select max(cbk)
    from tab 
   where cbk between start_date and end_date
     and ID = myID
)
   and ID = myID
 group by ID, cbk;
```

We may try for *id = 3* in *the demo*, since there's no *id = 3* for the latest date `2018-06-19` for whole table :

[*DB-Fiddle Demo*](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ky2mm7zsVNavDJmDWKRZJG/5)

Answer (score 0):

Solved like this (simplified):

```
SELECT v.id, max(v.due_31_60), max(v.due_61_90), v.cbk
      FROM my_table as v
      JOIN (select id, max(cbk) as max_date from my_table
           WHERE (cbk >= start_date and cbk <= end_date ) 
           GROUP BY id) as q 
      ON q.id = v.id and v.cbk = q.cbk
      GROUP BY v.id, v.cbk
```